# Firebase Admin SDK @Exclude annotation does not work

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I want to exclude a field when I create or update a document on Firestore.
It is a server application and I'm using Firebase Admin SDK. Many recommend using @Exclude on field (if is public) or on its getter, but it does not work.

Here the POJO:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.Exclude;    

public class User extends AbstractModel {

private String id;
private String name;

public User() {
}

@Exclude
public String getId() {return id;}

public void setId(String id) {this.id = id;}
```

Here the method to create the document:

```
    public void create(User user) {

        ApiFuture<DocumentReference> future = FirestoreClient.getFirestore().collection(USERS_COLLECTION).add(user);

    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[com.google.firebase.database.Exclude](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/database/Exclude) is for use with Realtime Database.  The Cloud Firestore java server SDK provides a different annotation, [com.google.cloud.firestore.annotation.Exclude](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/firestore/annotation/Exclude.html).